# How to join another physical server or VM as a node for a docker swarm machine?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-machine

Hi I have docker swarm in a physical server1, the docker worker join token command generated with a dummy IP, now I want to make another physical server2 in which docker installed as a worker node to docker swarm in physical server1.

So I cannot run the worker join token command as its has dummy IP of the manager node which physical server2 cannot reach.

I have connectivity between server1 and server2 though.

So how to handle this ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by this: "  the docker worker join token command generated with a dummy IP"?

Comment: @sxm1972 : When v initialize swarm it wil generate 2 commands with token to run on node right! one for making a node worker another to make a node manager.   That token command also has that swarm manager IP and Port , here the IP docker gives to machines is a IP which is dummy means only the host server in which docker running knows it another PHYSICAL server cannot connect it as that IP is internal.                                Now Iam trying to make that another PHYSICAL server as a worker for that I ran the worker-join-token command but since IP in the command is dummy its not reachable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-configure the advertisement address of Docker swarm manager. If the first machine is not a real production machine or you can deploy the code whenever you want, you can call easily the following command on the manager machine to re-initialize the docker swarm service with own new advertisement address.

```
$ docker swarm leave --force; \
docker swarm init --advertise-addr=<Server IP>
```

Then you can generate the worker token with 'join-token' command again:

```
$ docker swarm join-token worker
```

Please keep mind that the stack you deployed before is gonna be disappeared after you called `docker swarm leave --force`.

OR

You need to find a way to change the advertisement address.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The dummy IP will generate only when you have not mentioned your physical machine IP as your swarm API IP at the time of creating or initializing the docker swarm....
 If you give your machine IP as swarm API server IP at the time of initializing the swarm cluster at master node by specifying the `--advertice-addr=<IP of ur master node IP>`
      So this IP can use other VMs to join as worker nodes in your cluster..

Note: your IPs in same subnet.